Why are my log4j2-settings being ignored?
The log4j2.xml file is simple:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Configuration>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="stderr" target="SYSTEM_ERR">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="Meow %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="stderr"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
    
</Configuration>

I know, it is being read by the Java-program, because, if I introduce a deliberate syntax error into it, the program complains.
But, when it is clear, it is ignored. Messages are printed to standard error, but without the "Meow" prefix -- and without proper timestamps. Each line begins with a number (msecs since start?), thread ([main]) and level (INFO) instead of using the specified pattern:
1301 [main] INFO com.example.common.util.PFEAppUtil - Retreiving file contents
1303 [main] INFO com.example.common.util.PfeSmsDataUtils - Secrets from existing cache object ..

What am I doing wrong?
Update: having run with the -Dlog4j2.debug, I got the following additional entries from the StatusLogger printed before the first log-entry from our own code. Still don't understand, why my pattern is ignored :(
DEBUG StatusLogger Using ShutdownCallbackRegistry class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry
DEBUG StatusLogger Took 0,131474 seconds to load 255 plugins from jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@137e0d2
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy=UNCACHED (user specified null, default is UNCACHED)
TRACE StatusLogger Using default SystemClock for timestamps.
DEBUG StatusLogger org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.SystemClock supports precise timestamps.
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 48 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting LoggerContext[name=137e0d2, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@cf93bb]...
DEBUG StatusLogger Reconfiguration started for context[name=137e0d2] at URI null (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@cf93bb) with optional ClassLoader: null
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'ConfigurationFactory' found 6 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Missing dependencies for Yaml support, ConfigurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.yaml.YamlConfigurationFactory is inactive
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Missing dependencies for Json support, ConfigurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.json.JsonConfigurationFactory is inactive
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Using configurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory@15b7e8
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Closing FileInputStream java.io.FileInputStream@a41516
DEBUG StatusLogger Apache Log4j Core 2.20 initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/mi/sftdbaas/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml]
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Core' found 132 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 16 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
TRACE StatusLogger TypeConverterRegistry initializing.
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 26 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="Meow %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(/mi/sftdbaas/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 48 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
DEBUG StatusLogger ConsoleAppender$Builder(target="SYSTEM_ERR", follow="null", direct="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(Meow %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n), name="stderr", Configuration(/mi/sftdbaas/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml), Filter=null, ={})
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_ERR.false.false
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
DEBUG StatusLogger createAppenders(={stderr})
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
DEBUG StatusLogger createAppenderRef(ref="stderr", level="null", Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
DEBUG StatusLogger LoggerConfig$RootLogger$Builder(additivity="null", level="INFO", levelAndRefs="null", includeLocation="null", ={stderr}, ={}, Configuration(/mi/sftdbaas/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
DEBUG StatusLogger createLoggers(={root})
DEBUG StatusLogger Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/mi/sftdbaas/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml] initialized
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/mi/sftdbaas/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml]
DEBUG StatusLogger Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/mi/sftdbaas/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml] OK.
TRACE StatusLogger Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@b4fe2a...
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration notified 1 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
DEBUG StatusLogger OutputStream closed
DEBUG StatusLogger Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1, all resources released: true
DEBUG StatusLogger Appender DefaultConsole-1 stopped with status true
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 1 LoggerConfigs.
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@b4fe2a OK
TRACE StatusLogger Reregistering MBeans after reconfigure. Selector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector@1aa0fbd
TRACE StatusLogger Reregistering context (1/1): '137e0d2' org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@cf93bb
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=137e0d2'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=137e0d2,component=StatusLogger'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=137e0d2,component=ContextSelector'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=137e0d2,component=Loggers,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=137e0d2,component=Appenders,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=137e0d2,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=137e0d2,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=137e0d2,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=137e0d2
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=137e0d2,component=StatusLogger
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=137e0d2,component=ContextSelector
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=137e0d2,component=Loggers,name=
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=137e0d2,component=Appenders,name=stderr
TRACE StatusLogger Using default SystemClock for timestamps.
DEBUG StatusLogger org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.SystemClock supports precise timestamps.
TRACE StatusLogger Using DummyNanoClock for nanosecond timestamps.
DEBUG StatusLogger Reconfiguration complete for context[name=137e0d2] at URI /mi/sftdbaas/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@cf93bb) with optional ClassLoader: null
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
DEBUG StatusLogger LoggerContext[name=137e0d2, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@cf93bb] started OK.


Use -Dlog4j2.debug to check which configuration file is used.

Based on the debug it doesn't look like there is anything wrong (afaik), your file is being loaded correctly. Now then, is it possible that you have more than on dependency in your project that is overriding the log configurations to something else? Can you build a simple project just with the logs to test it and see if the same behavior happens?

@JorgeCampos, are you suspecting another -- conflicting -- log4j config-file trumping my settings? Wouldn't that be mentioned by the StatusLogger?

It all depends on how your project is setup. You didn't add any details so for instance if it is using a framework where the log configuration is relying on a properties file rather than the xml (spring for instance).

@MikhailT., are those log events generated by your application using the Log4j API? If you use another logging API or they come from a library, you might be missing some bridges (log4j-slf4j2-impl, log4j-jul, a bump of commons-logging to 1.3.0 etc.).

The actual logging in this code is not done through the log4j directly, but rather through slf4j.
And some older dependency (of a dependency) was dragging-in log4j-1.2 JARs so, as @jorge-campos and @piotr-p-karwasz suspected, the log-entries weren't processed by log4j2, but rather by the older (obsolete) version.
I sorted the dependencies out -- the mvn dependency:tree was of great help -- and now things work properly.
